# combinatorics help question, dont understand

Tags: combinatorics

I've got this maths question and i've no idea how to do it.

http://vvcap.net/db/iCEsjpXBaSTQDmRI6eYz.htp

The same question has been posted up on another forum, someone has given a solution, but i don't understand it. http://vvcap.net/db/Ttdif9ANgn2tkHesy4US.htp If anyone could explain to me what's going on in the second link, that'd be good. Cheers.

Please explain as basically as possile

Comment: second link: how many ways can I choose {0 even, 0 odd}{1 even, 1 odd}...{5 even, 5 odd}.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a set, $A$ that is all the numbers from $1$ to $11$. The first subset of $A$ you should look at is $\{2,4,6,8,10\}$, which is all the even numbers from $A$, notice there are $5$ of them. Now look at the subset $\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}$, the set of odd numbers in $A$, there are $6$ of them. We need to build subsets of $A$. So let's do it!

First, we note that the subset must have an even number of elements! Why? If it did not then we could not have the same amount of even and odd numbers. For example, if we tried to make a one element subset, then it would consists of a single odd and no evens or an even and no odds, which is a problem. So now we only need to make even subsets.

The easiest is a subset with $0$ elements chosen. There is only $1$ way to take an element from the set of even and odds (that is to choose none of them!). So this can be done in $1$ way.

Now let's make a subset with $2$ elements. This means we have to choose $1$ odd and $1$ even. There are $6$ total odd numbers, so we can do this in $\binom{6}{1}=6$ total ways. But we want to choose that AND an even number, which can be done in $\binom{5}{1}=5$ ways because there are $5$ even numbers. The AND 'logic' means we need to multiply. So the total number of $2$ element subsets of $A$ we could make is
$$
\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}=6(5)=30
$$

Let's go back to the $0$ subset we made. What did we do? We chose $0$ elements from the evens and $0$ elements from the odds. But isn't that $\binom{6}{0}$ and $\binom{5}{0}$? We choose $0$ from the evens AND $0$ from the odds, that gave us
$$
\binom{6}{0}\binom{5}{0}=1(1)=1
$$
ways to do it. Which is what we got!

So notice that in general, if we want to make a subset of $A$ by choosing $n$ elements from the evens and odds, we can do it in 
$$
\binom{6}{n}\binom{5}{n}
$$
ways!

We are almost done. We just need to figure out our $n$'s! We now we could choose $0$ from each set. We can do $1$. Et cetera. But notice we can't choose more than $5$ because though the odd number set has $6$ elements, the evens only has $5$ elements. So the most we can choose is $5$ elements from each set. So we need to do this for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5$. How do we get our answer. Well, we add them! Each one of them is a way we can make a subset of $A$ with equal amounts of odds and evens. So their total gives us all the ways to do it. Using what we found above, the total is...
$$
\binom{6}{0}\binom{5}{0}+\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{2}+\binom{6}{3}\binom{5}{3}+\binom{6}{4}\binom{5}{4}+\binom{6}{5}\binom{5}{5}
$$
$$
=1+30+150+200+75+6=462
$$
So there are $462$ total ways to make subsets using the numbers from $A$ so that there are the same number of even and odd numbers in the set! Hopefully, that cleared up your confusions.

EDIT: To answer your commented question:

That is multiplication as $\binom{6}{1}=6$ and $\binom{5}{1}=5$. Maybe you haven't learned this. But the amount of ways to choose $n$ objects from $T$ total things is 
$$
\binom{T}{n}
$$
You can read more about this [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Combination.html). Now this number is given by
$$
\binom{T}{n}=\frac{T!}{n!(T-n)!}
$$
In case you have never seen it for some reason, $T!$ means we multiply $T$ by all the numbers from $T$ down to $1$. So $5!=5\times 4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1=120$. We also define $0!=1$ Now lets go back to the example, we have
$$
\binom{6}{1}=\frac{6!}{1!(6-1)!}=\frac{6!}{1!5!}=\frac{6\cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{1 \times (5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)}=6
$$
Similarly, we have
$$
\binom{5}{1}=\frac{5!}{1!(5-1)!}=\frac{5!}{1!4!}=5
$$
So then 
$$
\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}=6(5)=30
$$
So you can do the same with all the rest of the numbers. Doing them in order yields the numbers written: $1$, $30$, $150$, $200$, $75$, and $5$, respectively.

Comment: you state above 6(5)=30 so you're timing the two top numbers. So for example for 6 2 and 5 2 how do we work this one out ? what do we times?

Comment: @joe See my answer. I added an edited section at the end to address your question.

Comment: you're the man  mathematics2x2life

Comment: are you still online, im struggling here..

Comment: i got my first one correct = 150, however the next ones are wrong i got 800 instead of 200 and 2700 instead of 75

Comment: @joe Maybe it would be just easier to make a list so you know what to multiply and divide. $0!=1$, $1!=1$, $2!=2$, $3!=6$, $4!=24$, $5!=120$, $6!=720$. So for the next one after the $150$, we have $\binom{6}{3}\binom{5}{3}=\frac{6!}{3!3!}\times \frac{5!}{3!2!}=\frac{720}{6*6}\times \frac{120}{6*2}=20 \times 10=200$. Try doing it this way instead.

Comment: That's just gotten me more confused. Could you please tell me what i was doing wrong on the previous method. (6up4down) 6/4!6-4) = 6/4!2! = 6*4*3*2*1/4(2*1) = 720/8 = 90

Comment: (5up4down) 5/!5-4! = 5/4!1! = 5*4*3*2*1/4x(1) = 120/4 = 30 so ..... 90x30=2700

Comment: @joe No! Be careful. $\binom{5}{3}$ means you get $5!$ in the numerator. In the denominator you have $3!$. But each time, you get the top number minus the bottom number in bottom too! So $\binom{5}{3}=\frac{5!}{3!\times(5-3)!}=\frac{5!}{3!\times3!}=\frac{120}{6\times6}=10$.

Comment: hmm wait i think i've noticed an error.

Comment: 1+30+150+200+75+5=462 that does not work out to be 462, it'd be 462. And where you got 5, i got 6... :o

Comment: Then that is probably correct. I did not bother to check the addition or the numbers. The $\binom{something}{something}$ sum is correct. I did not check the numbers produced by the link you posted and assumed their numbers were correct. I checked, the answer is indeed $462$. Indeed, the last number should be $6$ not $5$. But catching that mistake shows that you definitely followed it all!

Comment: Haha my friend who done an A at a level got 461 and 5 at the end :P i win. So you're certain it's 462, not 461 aha :P ? and cheers for the help Dude